# Server to AWS RDS - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: .net, sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, iis-8

I'm moving a website from a dedicated server to AWS.

First I want to transfer the database (sql server express).

I've setup an AWS RDS Sql Express database - and can connect to it from my PC. However when I update the database connection string on my current server - to point to the AWS RDS Sql Express, I get the error:

> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.)]

The Security Group the RDS belongs to has the following ports open:

[image: ports open]

One IP, is my local PC - the other is my dedicated server IP.

Any idea why my local PC will connect to the AWS RDS Sql Express instance, but my dedicated servers connection is refused?

Is there any way I can find what IP address my server is trying to connect to AWS with (if it's not the public facing one)?

Thanks for any advice.

Mark

Comment: In `Sql Server Configuration Manager`check if `TCP/IP` is enabled for all client protocols

Comment: Hi - on AWS RDS - you don't have access to the Sql Server instance directly - only through SSMS. I can open ports on the firewall - is that what you mean?

Comment: no that is not what I mean. I dont know AWS RDS, but normally you have to enable TCP/IP protocol on your sql server. For sql-server express it could be off by default. I dont think you can change it with SSMS

Comment: If I understand you  correct, your local pc can connect to the database, and the database is not on your local pc. So in that case TCP/IP is setup correct and you can ignore my comments

Comment: Thanks for trying to help anyway. On my dedicated servers firewall, port 443 outgoing is open.

Comment: @MarkTait note that it's not port 443, it's port 1433.  Security groups never "actively refuse" connections, so even if the security group is not correct, this is not the error that situation will trigger.  You'll see an error that the connection timed out.  Security groups with missing rules behave like a blackhole that simply ignores unexpected traffic.  The problem is almost certainly in your server, its firewall, or your server's network.

Comment: Hi Michael - by my server - do you mean the dedicated one, running my website that is trying to connect to AWS RDS, or the actual AWS RDS server? (thanks for your help)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Could you please add that as the answer - it's exactly what was wrong. My outgoing server (running my website) had 443 enabled, not 1433.  Thanks very much for your help - this is the solution to my problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you should check 2 things:

1- the rds endpoints  whether it is correct or not
(in my case the endpoint was wrong)

2- the rds got public accessible set to true and its security group allows your ip