# An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - error in Symfony

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, symfony, amazon-rds

I'm trying to connect to my aws rds database with symfony. But I constantly get an error: An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.". My security groups are open to all ports and here are my settings.

```
//services.yaml
parameters:
    database_driver:   pdo_mysql
    database_host:     '%env(RDS_HOSTNAME)%'
    database_port:     '%env(RDS_PORT)%'
    database_name:     '%env(RDS_DB_NAME)%'
    database_user:     '%env(RDS_USERNAME)%'
    database_password: '%env(RDS_PASSWORD)%'
```

```
//doctrine.yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:

        # if the url option is specified, it will override the above config
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                dbname: '%env(RDS_DB_NAME)%'
                user: '%env(RDS_USERNAME)%'
                password: '%env(RDS_PASSWORD)%'
                host: '%env(RDS_HOSTNAME)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                port: 3306
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

In .env you are the correct variables.
If someone has a fix, please provide it to me :)

Comment: Check Michael-sqlbot's comment on this [https://stackoverflow.com/q/56904952/2324206](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56904952/2324206)

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.
Currently, I'm a student and living in a student dorm. My dorm network is blocking the connection with an outside MySql server so that's why I repeatedly get this error.

The solution would be to use a non-public source of the internet or try to share internet from some other device. You could also use a VPN (make sure to test first because with some of them the same error ocurrs).